# Dual booting Win10 + Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu correctly (in UEFI mode), the only problem I've got now is that it won't load any manager to choose which OS to load at startup.
It goes directly to Windows 10 like nothing happened even though when I keep pressing esc at startup and then i go in in boot order with F9 and choose Ubuntu it loads normally but, as you can imagine, it's not that comfortable.

This is my pastebin from boot-repair that went apparently good: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12649013/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to boot into Windows and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** from within there.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** go to **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and uncheck Fast Boot. After these steps **shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Then reinstall GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**
Boot from the Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Now you can choose which operating system you want to boot from the GRUB boot loader menu.

Note :

`sda` = disk | `sda2` = efi partition | `sda8` = system partition
disk and partition numbers taken from your pastebin output

To get sure - check the partition numbers, you can easily identify them with **GParted**.
The (Graphic User Interface) tool is already included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: I've done every step you told me,now it's just slower to access Windows but nothing has really changed... EDIT:I just noticed that from power options I only see sleep and lock, fast boot option is not there anymore even though I'm sure to have that disabled since installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Same as before, from F9 boot order YES but not as I was trying to achieve

Comment: @Tatoalo : Please check in UEFI settings which system is the default one to boot. If it is Windows then change it to ubuntu and you should see the GRUB boot loader when starting the PC.

Comment: I've tried but from there I cannot change boot order...EDIT: BTW This is what I see on startup now:http://i58.tinypic.com/2ajxqqf.jpg

Comment: @Tatoalo : Please tell me : can you boot into both systems - into ubuntu and into Windows ?

Comment: Yes I can as before(from ESC and then F9) but It's not what I asked for in the first place...

Comment: As Identfier of the new entry in the BCD Store is correct to type {bootmgr}?

Comment: One last thing, I hope :D, from Ubuntu I can't execute the command you told me(even with sudo) , I get "dd: unrecognized operand 'linux.bin'"

Comment: I've finally managed to do it! I had to play a little with the efibootmgr to modify the boot order since it seems that HP UEFI is a really good way to have an headache! Thank you very much for your help throughout the evening, good night. :D