# Windows 10 entry not listed on Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I have installed Windows 10 Pro x64 on a Samsung SSD Pro 850 series device /dev/sda. Upgrading it from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro.

After that, in a second drive Samsung SSD '/dev/sdb' I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. (swap + primary partition).

During the installation I have installed grub in '/dev/sda'. And after restarting, the grub menu doesn't shows a Windows 10 entry. Only shows:

- Ubuntu.
- Windows recovery environment.

Should be disabled UEFI, in the Motherboard configuration? Currently is disabled.

Fast boot and Windows 10 hibernation is disabled as it is explained in [Dual booting Win10 + Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681148/dual-booting-win10-ubuntu-15-04).

Boot-Repair doesn't fix the problem. And now I have grub installed in sda and sdb, but I haven't reached a solution for dual boot (Win10-Ubuntu).

How can I repair grub?

Ubuntu Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12689656/

Comment: It shows "Windows recovery environment" here too, but Windows 10 boots alright. You could rename that entry.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  my problem was in my Windows installation. You are right.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" into the title. Write an answer and accept 24 hours later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the problem was not related to grub. The grub entry named 'Windows recovery environment' loads the bootloader correctly. But my system had a corrupt installation. A fresh installation of Windows 10  and a correctly reinstallation of grub (using boot repair) fixed the problem.

Comment: Issue is that grub has yet to be updated to search for Windows 10. I guess last choice is recovery if no other entry matches.